# Grails extension in SpringSource Tool Suite errors

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-plugin, sts-springsourcetoolsuite, springsource

I recently installed SpringSource Tool Suite. And I want to start working with Grails projects. So, I went to the Dashboard -> Extension, where I saw two extensions: Grails (current production release) and Grails Support as in the image below.

[image]

But when I try to install them, I get the following errors :

```
Problems occurred while performing installation: Operation details
Operation details
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
Software currently installed: Shared profile 1.0.0.1340820181092 (SharedProfile_com.springsource.sts.ide 1.0.0.1340820181092)
Missing requirement: Shared profile 1.0.0.1340820181092 (SharedProfile_com.springsource.sts.ide 1.0.0.1340820181092) requires 'org.maven.ide.eclipse [1.0.100.20110804-1717]' but it could not be found
```

What can I do to resolve this error ? Or are there any other options I can follow to install Grails extension?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, what @BurtBeckwith said.  You should move to the new GGTS.

However, to address your particular problem, you installed STS into a read-only directory (or in C:\Program files).  You need to re-install it somewhere else.

The Eclipse p2 installer cannot handle installing feature patches into a read-only directory.  Groovy-Eclipse ships with a feature patch to extend the JDT compiler.  I believe that this problem was fixed in the Juno release of Eclipse (4.2), which came out last week.

Comment: Thank you Andrew! It worked when I re-installed it right under C: drive.

Answer (score 2):

I would switch to the new "Groovy/Grails Tool Suite" that was recently announced (see http://www.springsource.org/node/3582). Go to the standard download page at http://www.springsource.org/downloads/sts and click "Other Downloads >". Download the version for your OS under "Milestone Version - Groovy/Grails Tool Suite 3.0.0.M2".

It is a beta/milestone release but I've been using it since it was released and it's as stable as a final release so far. It's convenient since the Groovy-Eclipse plugin and the Grails support are already configured for you, in addition to the latest Grails (2.0.4). Any other plugins that you need from the standard STS can always be installed using the standard install/update procedure.

Answer (score 1):

Deleting corresponding application from Windows memory removed the problem (Grails extension in SpringSource Tool Suite errors). Double running applications (earlier and new) could also be reason why GGS or STS sometimes cannot save .groovy files (with error message or without).